# I need help understanding stylesheets

Tags: html, css

This is a homework question. It is not for a grade (FYI).But we have to study the questions for our final exam. I lost this particular question and need to better understand how to derive to the answers. Please see question below:

Consider this style sheet:

```
.x{ color: blue;}

.y{ font-size: 16pt;}

.z {font-style: italic; color: red;}
```

Match the following text with its appearance.

```
A. 16pt
B. red, italic 
C. blue, italic
D. blue

1. < span class=x > TEXT < /span>

2. < span class=y> TEXT < /span>  

3. < span class=x> < span class="z">TEXT< /span > < /span>    

4. < span class=z > < span class=x>TEXT< /span>< /span>
```

Can anyone help me understand this better?

Comment: Okay, what do you understand so far?

Comment: even we can't understand your question and code

Answer (score 5):

**1 -> D** (class x contains color blue)

**2 -> A** (class y contains 16pt font-size property)

**3 -> B** (as per CSS precedence, class z will be applied to option 3 which will make TEXT red and italic)

**4 -> C** (class z will be applied first which will make TEXT red and italic, then class x will be applied which will make TEXT blue)

CSS in action:

```css
.x {color: blue;}

.y {font-size: 16pt;}

.z {font-style: italic; color: red;}
```

```html
<span class=x>TEXT</span>

<span class=y>TEXT</span>  

<span class=x><span class=z>TEXT</span></span>    

<span class=z><span class=x>TEXT</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

class=x corresponds to .x from the stylesheet

so when you see class=x from the html in question one you should look back to the stylesheet. In the stylesheet you can see that the color attribute is being assigned a value of blue. Now the TEXT that this style is being applied too will be blue.

follow the same procedure for the rest of the questions